# Sql server distinct keyword in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Hi all i need a help in getting data from sql database to datagrid.
I want to count distinct values and put it into the datagrid column which is also a distinct value like this:-

> ```
> | Partyname | Turbo | Truck | Total |
> +-----------+-------+-------+-------+
> | Abc       | 33    | 3     | 36    |
> | xyz       | 30    | 10    | 40    |
> | qwe       | 2     | 4     | 6     |
> ```

But what i'm getting is this!:-

> ```
> | Partyname | Turbo | Truck | Total |
> +-----------+-------+-------+-------+
> | Abc       |       |       |       |
> | xyz       |       |       |       |
> | qwe       |       |       |       |
> ```

And my code is:-

```
  Dim sCommand, cmd As SQLCommand
    Dim sadp As SQLDataAdapter
    Dim sds As New DataSet
    Dim stable As New DataTable
    Private Sub OK_Button_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
        Dim sts As String = ""
        Dim dt, dt2 As String
        dt = (Date_from.Value.Date).ToShortDateString + " " + (DateTimeInput1.Text)
        dt2 = (Date_to.Value.Date).ToShortDateString + " " + (DateTimeInput2.Text)
        Try
            Credit_report_daily.Show()
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "SELECT Distinct Party_name FROM Weightment Where Cash_Cr='Credit' AND (Weigh_date Between @dt AND @dt2) Group by Party_name"
            Using com As New SqlCommand(sql, Con)
                Con.Open()
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Parse(dt))
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", DateTime.Parse(dt2))
                sadp = New SqlDataAdapter(com)
                sds = New DataSet()
                sadp.Fill(sds, "General")
                stable = sds.Tables("General")
                Credit_report_daily.DataGridView1.DataSource = sds.Tables("General")
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = Con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct Vehicle_Type FROM Weightment Where Cash_Cr='Credit' AND (Weigh_date Between @dt AND @dt2) Group by Vehicle_Type"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Parse(dt))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", DateTime.Parse(dt2))
                Dim da As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While da.Read
                    Credit_report_daily.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(da.Item(0), da.Item(0))
                End While
                da.Close()
                Con.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Can you plz help me??????

i'm Getting column by counting how many distinct values are their in Column Vehicle_type
Like this:-

```
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                    cmd.Connection = Con
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct Vehicle_Type FROM Weightment Where Cash_Cr='Credit' AND (Weigh_date Between @dt AND @dt2) Group by Vehicle_Type"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Parse(dt))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", DateTime.Parse(dt2))
                    Dim da As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    While da.Read
                        Credit_report_daily.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(da.Item(0), da.Item(0))
                    End While
                    da.Close()
                    Con.Close()
```

Comment: i think Turbo, Truck, Total are columns of your table ,am i right? then where did u take these column values from database?anyway can u put your db here. i think it will be helpful to ans.

Comment: specify what are the output columns and how it should look like?

Comment: I'm Getting column from database by counting distinct values like this:-                                                              `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct Vehicle_Type FROM Weightment Where Cash_Cr='Credit' AND (Weigh_date Between @dt AND @dt2) Group by Vehicle_Type"`

Answer (score 0):

Add count for `Party_name` i.e. `select Party_name,count(Party_name) FROM Weightment...`. Same for the second query.

Comment: But how to add that value to a specific vehicle column.

Comment: I Mean that it will create another column and put its value not in same column.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if `CTE` would be useful or working in your case. But one of the solution can be this.

;

```
With CTEPartyCount as 
(SELECT Party_name, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Truck order by Truck) AS Truck_Count,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Turbo order by Turbo) AS Turbo_Count
FROM Weightment Where Cash_Cr='Credit' AND (Weigh_date Between @dt AND @dt2)
)

Select distinct Party_name,max(Truck_Count),max(Turbo_Count) from CTEPartyCount
group by Party_name
```

Comment: The column name is not fix it is created as how many vehicle is their

Comment: The distinct of vehicle is done and then other part.